# Will a breadcrumb error in structured data markup result in Google not displaying my rich snippet?

Tags: google, wordpress, structured-data, breadcrumbs, yoast

Will a breadcrumb error in structured data markup cause Google not to show that rich snippet? I use Schema App, but then I got the premium version of Yoast SEO and I noticed the problem when I test the page in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool. Thought I read if you have any errors, Google won't show the rich snippet - is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Please provide more details on what the actual error you're seeing otherwise it will difficult to come up with the correct solution. Also if you're using plugins then errors can be fixed with correct options unless the issue with the plugin code(in that case need to go manual or switch to alternative plugin).

Also to partially answer your question. There 3 potential outcomes:

1. Google Algorithm detects the right breadcrumb structure even though your structured data is wrong.
2. Due to error in the structured data then google will take wrong breadcrumb structure for your web page.
3. Or it can completely ignore it.